# Defining a Function for Multiple Types

Tags: haskell, types

How is a function defined for different types in Haskell?
Given

```
func :: Integral a => a -> a
func x = x
func' :: (RealFrac a , Integral b) => a -> b
func' x = truncate x
```

How could they be combined into one function with the signature

```
func ::  (SomeClassForBoth a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

Comment: Those types look pretty different to me - one of them's `a -> a` and the other's `a -> b`. Plus, type classes don't allow you to choose behaviour based on which instances are in scope - someone could add an instance later. It's all resolved at compile time

Comment: This looks as an XY problem. Why do you need those two functions to share the same name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a typeclass.

```
class    TowardsZero a      where towardsZero :: Integral b => a -> b
instance TowardsZero Int    where towardsZero = fromIntegral
instance TowardsZero Double where towardsZero = truncate
-- and so on
```

Possibly a class with an associated type family constraint is closer to what you wrote (though perhaps not closer to what you had in mind):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
import GHC.Exts

class TowardsZero a where
    type RetCon a b :: Constraint
    towardsZero :: RetCon a b => a -> b

instance TowardsZero Int where
    type RetCon Int b = Int ~ b
    towardsZero = id

instance TowardsZero Double where
    type RetCon Double b = Integral b
    towardsZero = truncate

-- and so on
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend this, but you can hack at it with a GADT:

```
data T a where
    T1 :: a -> T a
    T2 :: RealFrac a => a -> T b

func :: Integral a => T a -> a
func (T1 x) = x
func (T2 x) = truncate x
```

The `T` type says, "Either you already know the type of the value I'm wrapping up, or it's some unknown instance of `RealFrac`". The `T2` constructor existentially quantifies `a` and packs up a `RealFrac` dictionary, which we use in the second clause of `func` to convert from (unknown) `a` to `b`. Then, in `func`, I'm applying an `Integral` constraint to the `a` which may or may not be inside the `T`.

Comment: That's pretty clever!

Comment: You haven't really done anything... you still need to decide somewhere whether to construct a `T1` or a `T2`, and at that point you might as well decide whether to say `trunc` or `id`

Comment: @luqui I agree. It's not very idiomatic Haskell to try to dispatch runtime behaviour based on type class availability (which is how I'm interpreting OP's question)

Answer (score 2):

This is known as *ad hoc polymorphism*, where you execute different code depending on the type.  The way this is done in Haskell is using typeclasses.  The most direct way is to define a new class

```
class Truncable a where
    trunc :: Integral b => a -> b
```

And then you can define several concrete instances.

```
instance Truncable Integer where trunc = fromInteger
instance Truncable Double where trunc = truncate
```

This is unsatisfying because it requires an instance for each concrete type, when there are really only two families of identical-looking instances.  Unfortunately, this is one of the cases where it is hard to reduce boilerplate, for technical reasons (being able to define "instance families" like this interferes with the open-world assumption of typeclasses, among other difficulties with type inference).  As a hint of the complexity, note that your definition assumes that there is no type that is both `RealFrac` and `Integral`, but this is not guaranteed -- which implementation should we pick in this case?

There is another issue with this typeclass solution, which is that the `Integral` version doesn't have the type

```
trunc :: Integral a => a -> a
```

as you specified, but rather

```
trunc :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

Semantically this is not a problem, as I don't believe it is possible to end up with some polymorphic code where you don't know whether the type you are working with is `Integral`, but you do need to know that when it is, the result type is the same as the incoming type.  That is, I claim that whenever you would need the former rather than the latter signature, you already know enough to replace `trunc` by `id` in your source.  (It's a gut feeling though, and I would love to be proven wrong, seems like a fun puzzle)

There may be performance implications, however, since you might unnecessarily call `fromIntegral` to convert a type to itself, and I think the way around this is to use [`{-# RULES #-}` definitions](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html), which is a dark scary bag of complexity that I've never really dug into, so I don't know how hard or easy this is.

Comment: "I claim that whenever you would need the former rather than the latter signature, you already know enough to replace trunc by id in your source" - this is the right answer. I was trying to articulate something along those lines in an edit to my answer but I needn't bother now :)

Comment: I propose a solution for which `trunc (3 :: Int)` infers the type `Int` rather than `Integral b => b`, and for which `trunc (3 :: Double)` is still polymorphic over the `Integral` instance; you may like it.

Comment: @DanielWagner ah cool, that is nice, addresses the performance issue I was worried about.